# VLOOKUP not displaying anything

Tags: excel

I'm trying to compare two servers list to see which servers has not agent installed. On the Row A are all the servers that we have (725 cells) and on Row B we have (540 cells) servers that has agent installed. Lastly on the row C I would want to display missing servers that has not agent yet.

I'm trying following formula on the Row C:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$A$725,1,FALSE)),A2, "")
```

but nothing seems to happen

[image]

What am I now missing here so that this is not working for me?

Running Excel-365 and with following version

[image]

Comment: If I read the formula you get a result from `VLOOKUP()`, check against `ISERROR()`. The latter will return `FALSE` meaning the 3rd parameter of the `IF()` it is nested in is returned; an empty string >> You see nothing. 2nd: To top that: you are refering in the 2nd parameter of `VLOOKUP()` to the range your formula is in.... not going to work! Note: Rows are horizontal, Columns vertical.

Comment: Your lookup table range should be `$B$2:$B$725` not `$B$2:$A$725`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FILTER()` function to get list of servers, agents are not installed.

```
=FILTER(A2:A4,COUNTIF(B2:B725,A2:A4)=0)
```

If you want list to rows for not installed servers then can use-

```
=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,B2:$B$725,0))),A2,"")
```

Or `BYROW()` for array approach-

```
=BYROW(A2:A4,LAMBDA(x,IF(ISERROR(XMATCH(x,B2:B725)),x,"")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing I don't understand, is the fact that you are using `VLookup(...,...,1,...)`: as far as I understand `VLookup()` is used for following case:

```
a    b    c
1   10  100
2   20  200
3   30  300
```

... and you want to find the value in the 'c' column, corresponding with value 2 in column 'a'. In that case you are looking for value 2 and you look in the third column, something like `VLookup(...,...,3,...)`.

However, if you're just looking for that value itself, instead of using `VLookup(lookup_value,range,1,exact_match)`, you can use `Match(lookup_value,range,exact_match)`.

Comment: He uses that because, if the vlookup returns an error it means that the value of column A was not found in column B. And with the if(iserror(xxxx)) he detects the missing values.

Comment: @AdrianFischer: this can be done with `=Match()` too, the results are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Replace:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$A$725,1,FALSE)),A2, "")
```

with:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$725,1,FALSE)),A2, "")
```

The range should be only the B column.